# Account clean up log out hook not working correctly in Mavericks

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks

I created a bash script to run on log out that goes through and deletes users except for a specific subset of users. The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Logout script to remove nonadmin accounts from Users folder
# Script deletes by name, not by admin rights, as to not mess with 
# group settings.


# TO SET UP SCRIPT, RUN COMMAND sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook /some/path/name/to/script


# If user is an admin, exit script 
if [ $USER = "admin" ] || [ $USER = "cas_admin" ] ; then 
echo "LOGOUT: admin folders will not be deleted."

# This for loop is a redundancy system, to delete any user accounts that may have   
# been left over from a quick shut down.

for dir in /Users/*
    do
        if [ $dir != "/Users/admin" ] && [ $dir != "/Users/cas_admin" ] && [ $dir != "/Users/Shared" ]; then 
            echo ${dir}
            rm -R $dir 
            dscl . -delete $dir 
        fi 
    done

exit 1
fi 

# If home directory exists, delete 
if [ -d "/Users/$USER" ]; then 
    echo "LOGOUT: user account cleanup."
    rm -R /Users/"$USER" 
    dscl . -delete /Users/"$USER"   
fi 

# This for loop is a redundancy system, to delete any user accounts that may have   
# been left over from a quick shut down.

for dir in /Users/*
do
    if [ $dir != "/Users/admin" ] && [ $dir != "/Users/cas_admin" ] && [ $dir != "/Users/Shared" ] ; then 
        echo ${dir}
        rm -R $dir 
        dscl . -delete $dir 
    fi 
done

exit 0
```

This code is executed on log out using LogoutHook and works perfectly fine in X.6-X.8. However in X.9 Mavericks, the script only works correctly if run directly in bash (deleting both the user's directory and removes the user from the user list), but when run from a LogoutHook, the entire /Users directory gets deleted but the users themselves do not. If the machine is restarted and you select a user from the login screen, the machine goes through the Apple initial setup and generates a new /Users directory and a new directory for the user in question. From the little bit of looking around I have done Login/Logout hooks have issues working with Mavericks, but none of the other solutions I have seen seem to pertain to this issue. This will be used for a computer lab setting and we cannot downgrade to X.8, any suggestions?

Comment: First obvious things is that you should quote all your arguments properly e.g. `if [ "$dir" ...`, `rm -R "$dir"`, etc. Second is that your script is probably getting run by a very old shell. I think `!=` is not supported in those shells. You can do `[ ! "$dir" = "something" ]` instead.

Comment: try #!/bin/bash -x and use a log file to log output of what this script is doing. You'll find why.

Comment: If there is a `/Users/Deleted Users` directory, it is expanded to `/Users/Deleted` and `Users` by `rm -R $dir`. (If that was the issue, you might delete this question because it is unlikely to help people who get here from search engines.)

Comment: @konsolebox OS X comes with bash 3.2 (the last GPLv2 version) which does support `!=`.

Comment: @Lri It may. However he said *"if run directly in bash (deleting both the user's directory and removes the user from the user list), but when run from a LogoutHook, the entire /Users directory gets deleted but the users themselves do not"*, so I see a chance in there.

Comment: @konsolebox I tried your changes and first of all, adding quotations to all the $dir arguments just made it so every user directory was deleted when run directly in bash, even the admin accounts. Secondly, before that I tried your operator change which did work in bash but when installed as a LogoutHook did not do anything.

Comment: @pttry_jcb You can check if your script is still being run by the same environment with `echo "$USER" > /some/file` and looking at the contents of the file after. You can also dump all those varibles with `set > /some/file2`. `BASH_VERSION` must be set if bash is really the one that's running the script. See also if posix mode gets enabled with `shopt -o posix > /some/file3`. Lastly, you can try redirecting your stdout and stderr to another file with `exec &>/some/file4` placed at the beginning of the script (not before `#!/bin/bash` of course).

Comment: I scrapped most of the code as it is just redundant and isn't touched as the script as run as root when in a log out hook, the new code just contains `for dir in /Users/*
do
    if [ $dir != "/Users/admin" ] && [ $dir != "/Users/cas_admin" ] && [ $dir != "/Users/Shared" ] ; then 
        echo ${dir}
        rm -R $dir 
        dscl . -delete $dir 
    fi 
done

exit 0`

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue and found that $USER environment variable is no longer available in OS X 10.9 on LogoutHook script. That should have been the reason why your initial script stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The script finally works after removing most of the code to:

```
for dir in /Users/*
  do
    if [ ! "$dir" = "/Users/admin" ] && [ ! "$dir" = "/Users/cas_admin" ] && [ ! "$dir" = "/Users/Shared" ] ; then 
      echo ${dir}
      rm -R $dir 
      dscl . -delete $dir 
    fi 
  done

exit 0
```

following @konsolebox suggestions and changing ownership to root, permissions to rwx--x--x, and using a different text editor (dos to unix headaches). Thank you for all the help.